# Apply function to Pandas Data Frame Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply the below function to a column in my pandas data frame. 
The column has entries like such --- > EMS: Diabetic Emergency

I am trying to split the entry and return the reason - ie Diabetic Emergency but free of the space after the ':'

I have tried the following:

```
def splitandstrip(column):
    for i in column:
        new = i.split(':')[1]
        new.strip()
    return new
df['response_reason'] = df.title.apply(splitandstrip)
```

Comment: `strip()` is not inplace it return a new string. You have to use `return new.strip()`

Comment: no need to apply a function here, you can use `series.str` methods like `df['response_reason']=df['response_reason'].str.split(':').str[1].str.strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not work as expected because `str.strip` returns a new string. The original string is unchanged. You could use

```
def splitandstrip(element):
   return element.split(':')[1].strip()
```

I would suggest using the `Series.str` accessor for vectorized string operations:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['EMS: Diabetic Emergency', 'ABC: DEF'], columns=['A'])
>>> df
                         A
0  EMS: Diabetic Emergency
1                 ABC: DEF
>>> df['A'].str.split(':').str.get(1).str.strip()
0    Diabetic Emergency
1                   DEF
Name: A, dtype: object
```